# How to keep PyQT diaglog incase input is invalid (lead to error in code)

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5

When use tinker to make GUI, if I give some input value lead to error in code (e.g lead to array out of range) the GUI dialog is still keeping and I can try it many times. But when I use in pyQT5, the dialog is close immediately and I must run GUI again . (It work property when the input is ok)

My PyQT run

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Ui_MainWindow()
    w = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ex.setupUi(w)
    w.show()
    try:
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
    except:
        print("Exiting")
```

Is there any solution to keep the dialog remain on error in python?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to keep QDialog persist when user didn't input a value or give wrong value. Just call the function that show QDialog again.

```py
# import your Ui_Dialog here

class FooDialog(QDialog, Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.cancel_action.clicked.connect(self.close)
        self.ok_action.clicked.connect(self.accept)



# in other file where you need to call FooDialog
import FooDialog

# .... other code
    def prompt_foo_dialog(self):
        foo_dlg = FooDialog()
        accepted = foo_dlg.exec_()
        if accepted:
            # ask for filename example
            filename = foo_dlg.filename_widget.text()
            if filename:
                # play with filename
            else:
                QMessageBox.warning(self, "", "Please supply a value")
                self.prompt_foo_dialog() # <--- Just call the function again
```

Comment: HI Azzamsa,
I have tried this one, but the problem is the dialog is stop when call foo_dlg.exec_(), and I cannot intervent to keep the dialog not stop working

Comment: If you want the GUI to 'not closed' even if the input value will break your code. I suggest that you use try/except. call the dialog again in the except sections.

Comment: This will create a new qdialog object, not maintain the state of the existing one